# Prevent angular from registering a certain anchor tag

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS registers the  tag as a directive. Now I have one link which needs to be registred by another jquery script, but angular is preventing that handler from being triggered it seems because it takes priority with it's handler.

Is there a way I can prevent Angular from doing this?

this is 'the code'

```
<a class="handlerclass" href="?some=action">test tekst</a>
```

I see that 2 handlers are attached to it; the first function is this one:

```
function (a){
"use strict";
 c.attr("href")||a.preventDefault()}
```

And that is not the function I want attached

Comment: Share the code please...

Comment: angular only registers the tag if you don't restrict the directive declaration - ie. `restrict: 'A'`